# Is this grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality

Using MS Word, I typed, "As Roblin and Adelaide are reading the reviews, Roblin thinks that women may get the vote and their rights after all.

MS Word puts a green squiggle under "reviews," and it asks me to change the comma to a semi colon. If I do, however, my entire sentence is wrong. What can I change to make it correct?

Comment: The best thing to change to make it correct is to turn off Word's grammar checker. It will then no longer be flagged as wrong, as indeed it is not.

Answer (score 3):

> As Roblin and Adelaide are reading the reviews, Roblin thinks that women may get the vote and their rights after all.

Semicolon wouldn’t make any sense in this case. It would break apart the sentence needlessly. After re-reading it a few times I think that keeping the comma there is the best thing you can do without rewording the sentence or the tense you are working in.

Comment: I agree, this sentence can not be made correct without rewording it, and it's the tense that seems incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to change the sentence at all. There is nothing wrong with it. MS Word is incorrect in suggesting that it should be changed. The automatic correction rules do make a lot of mistakes.